# Alphanumeric Validation in struts2-validation.xml

Tags: validation, struts2

I am using text filed for product name. Type of this field is String.

I want to validate the field with 0-9,a-z,A-Z and not allow special chrs and only numbers without alphabets.

productName1234>> Valid input

1234>> inValid input.

My Code in Validation.xml is as follows.

```
<validator type="requiredstring">
    <param name="fieldname">productName</param>
    <message>Please select product Name.</message>
</validator>

<validator type="regex">
    <param name="fieldname">productName</param>
    <param name="expression">^[,a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$</param>
    <message>Product name should accept only in AlphaNumeric.</message>
</validator>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. What i have to use in validation.xml

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression must be something like that

^\d+$|^[A-Za-z]+$

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
<validator type="regex">
    <param name="fieldname">productName</param>
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[^\d+$|^[A-Za-z]+$]]></param>
    <message>Product name should accept only in AlphaNumeric.</message>
</validator>
```